# ifdef in Makefile.am

Tags: c++, c, makefile, autotools

I want to use flags to compile my C project:

in configure.ac I Define the default model

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(model, [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-model],
    [specify which Model will be used; (default --enable-model=98]))],,
    [AC_DEFINE(MODEL_98)])

AS_IF([test "x$enable_model" = "x98"], [AC_DEFINE(MODEL_98)])
AS_IF([test "x$enable_model" = "x181"], [AC_DEFINE(MODEL_181)])
```

and then in Makefile.am i use these variable as following :

```
proj_SOURCES =          \
    ../bac.c        \
    ../conf.c               \
    ../cw.c             \

ifdef $(MODEL_98)
proj_SOURCES +=                                 \
    ../dm/98/interfaces.c               \
    ../dm/98/device.c                   \
    ../dm/98/ging.c         \
    ../dm/98/wa.c                   

endif
ifdef $(MODEL_181)
proj_SOURCES +=                                 \
    ../dm/181/fi.c
endif
```

but the project doesn't compile !!

what wrong in my Makefile.am

Thanks

Comment: Looks  like less than half of your many questions are accepted.  Are so many of the answers that weak?

Answer (score 5):

In order to use the variables in Makefiles, you need to use the `automake` versions, that is `AM_*` not `AC_`.

I would be using [`AM_CONDITIONAL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Usage-of-Conditionals.html). For your example:

In **configure.ac**:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([model], 
              [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-model],
                [specify which Model will be used; (default --enable-model=98]))],
              [enable_model=$enableval],
              [enable_model=98])

 AM_CONDITIONAL([MODEL_98],  [test "x$enable_model" = "x98"])
 AM_CONDITIONAL([MODEL_181], [test "x$enable_model" = "x181"])
```

This means we can call configure to enable model 98 as

- `./configure`
- `./configure --enable-model=98`

Then you can also enable 181 by calling configure as `./configure --enable-model=181`. Or for that matter any model number as we set `enable_model` to be the value passed in.

Then in your **Makefile.am**:

```
proj_SOURCES =             \
    ../bac.c               \
    ../conf.c              \
    ../cw.c                \

if MODEL_98
proj_SOURCES +=            \
    ../dm/98/interfaces.c  \
    ../dm/98/device.c      \
    ../dm/98/ging.c        \
    ../dm/98/wa.c                   

endif
if MODEL_181
proj_SOURCES +=            \
    ../dm/181/fi.c
endif
```

Note the use of `if` and not `ifdef` and the lack of quoting around `MODEL_98`.